# Does tinymce 3.x support IE 11?

Tags: browser, tinymce, internet-explorer-11, compatibility

Currently using tinymce 3.5.8 version and getting reports of few issues on IE11.
I know tinymce version 4.x does support IE 11 but wondering if any 3.x version of it does ?